# How does AWS Elastic Beanstalk run a Java application?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an Elastic Beanstalk app on AWS using Java. When I run 'eb deploy' is it able to just magically find my .jar file among those uploaded? (I'm trying to demystify the magical part) I'm using Gradle to build my application so there's also a gradle-wrapper.jar in the files that I push to AWS. I'm not sure how it elects to run the correct jar file. (which is under build/libs/myApp.jar)

When I ran a NodeJS app on AWS before, there was a spot in the configuration section in the console where you could input the "run command" for the Node project. So I knew what command it was running to initiate my app (very nice). There is no such thing for Java project on AWS.

I'm struggling to find any documentation on this. Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html

This describes a bit about what AWS will do by default to run your Java application. It also talks about how to have more control over your app via Procfiles or Buildfiles. I ended up having to add a Procfile to my application to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your Elastic BeanStalk creates an environment for you to run your application. This environment consits of an EC2 machine, the OS and bunch of other configurations. So the jar is actually run in EC2 machine inside the beanstalk. You can think of it as a java -jar operation happening in your EC2 (for you to easily understand).

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I understand how EB and EC2 work. What I'm trying to figure out is how the EC2 machine determines what .jar to run for the application, since I can't specify a run command in the console for Java apps on AWS.